# Merging two different data type of array list in to a single array list

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to merge two different array list data-types, and obtain the output in combined form, for example merging the below two types,

i have used for each and for loop

```java
        private ArrayList<String> typeOfBulb = new ArrayList<>();
        private ArrayList<Integer> manufcId = new ArrayList<>();
```

```java
        for(int i=0;i<companyName.size();i++){
            for(int j=0;j<companyName.size();j++){
                merge.add(companyName.get(i)+" "+typeOfBulb.get(j));
            }
        }
```

#### Obtained output

```
[Havells 250, Crompton 70, Crompton 250, Surya 70, Surya 250, Surya 70,
 Bajaj 70, Bajaj 50, Bajaj 100, Bajaj 1000
```

#### Expecting

```
Bajaj       250
Havells     50
Crompton    70
Surya       100
Bajaj       1000
```

Comment: Where is the Integer list involved in this problem?

Comment: You should show your `for` loop

Comment: What is the relation between a list of string, a list of integer and an output without integer?

Comment: What is the input? Show how you get hte current ouput

Comment: i am unable to edit the question

Comment: You need to accept or reject current suggested edit first.

Comment: i have updated the question, along with the suggested edit . kindly look in to the code

Comment: Create a Bulbs class where **typeOfBulb** and **manufcId** are class members which have Getter and Setter methods. That way you can do: `ArrayList<Bulbs> bulbs = new ArrayList<>();`. That way you don't need to create two parallel ArrayLists to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is to create a class that will store the type of bulb and manufacturer id. Then create an array list (or a simple array) of your new class to store the data.

```
public class Bulb{

    int manufcId;
    String manufcName;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        //return custom string for easy printing if wanted
    }
}


ArrayList<Bulb> bulbs = new ArrayList<>();
```